# Como atualizar aplicação Java de formato .war para diversos clientes?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

Tenho um servidor tomcat 8.5 e fiz o deploy de um arquivo .war. O mesmo funciona perfeitamente. A minha questão é, cada cliente possui um servidor implantado em sua empresa, então vou distribuir o mesmo arquivo .war para diversos clientes.

Qual é o melhor caminho para criar uma rotina de atualização automática no servidor destes clientes? Creio que muitas pessoas tenham passado por este problema, qualquer resposta será bem vinda.

Comment: Boa tarde Pedro, nem todos. Eu contornei essa situação criando um mediador que registra de tempo em tempo o ip do cliente. Já que o backend está no cliente, ele envia as informações de ip interno e externo do mesmo. Sei que existe no-ip, mas descartei essa questão.

Comment: bom, no Wildfly existe o Jboss-cli, que é um CLI que permite conectar remoto e fazer deploy.. acredito que exista algo parecido pro tomcat. Não sei como é seu processo de integração contínua, mas acho válido, por exemplo, após uma "release", rodar um script que vai de ip em ip fazendo o deploy das novas aplicações

Comment: https://github.com/tomcatmanager/tomcatmanager

Comment: ou pode tomar o caminho inverso, ter uma aplicação no cliente que busca no seu repositório uma versão mais recente

Comment: Obrigado, vou ler sobre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transferindo meus comentários para um resposta:

Não sabemos o seu cenário por completo, mas tenho algumas indicações:

- Deploy remoto

[Essa aplicação](http://github.com/tomcatmanager/tomcatmanager) te permite fazer o deploy de um .war em um IP externo. Sabendo os IPs dos clientes, você pode gerar um script que vai de IP em IP fazendo o deploy da nova versão.

```
connect http://IP_DO_CLIENTE:8080/manager usuario senha
deploy aplicacao.war
```

Não sei se existe um processo de integração contínua na sua empresa. Se sim, podes associar a execução ao final de uma nova release, por exemplo.

- "Atualizador"

Podes também desenvolver uma aplicação que atua como um atualizador, que, de tempos em tempos, vai em um repositório e verifica se existe uma versão mais recente daquele artefato. Se sim, baixa e faz o novo deploy

As duas abordagens tem suas dificuldades técnicas e de implantação. Sugiro que tome essa resposta como um norte para poder aprofundar suas pesquisas :)